# javascript setAttribute 'className' works onLoad, but not onClick

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Why does the following work for onLoad, and not onClick, and what would be the solution?
Thanks in advance...

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <LINK href=CSS/showdetails.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet />
</head>
<body OnLoad="javascript:showdetails()">

<script language=JavaScript src=js/showdetails.js type=text/javascript></script>

<div id="divResults" style="OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 480px;">
<span id="ShowResults" style="VISIBILITY: hidden">Display Results</span>
<p><input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var btn = document.getElementById('Button1');
btn.onclick = function() {showdetails();};

function showdetails() {
    var xc = document.getElementById('ShowResults');

    var top_ul = document.createElement('ul');
    top_ul.setAttribute('className','detclass');


    var li1 = document.createElement('li');
    li1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('craig'));


    var ul2 = document.createElement('ul');
    var li2 = document.createElement('li');
    li2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Mike'));

    ul2.appendChild(li2);


    li1.appendChild(ul2);
    top_ul.appendChild(li1);

    xc.appendChild(top_ul);

    var vis = "visible";
    xc.style.visibility = vis;
    }
</script>                 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls use the code tag next time, is much easier to read.

Comment: put scripts at bottom, just before </body> tag, solves everything related to this proble...

Comment: What exactly is working onload but not onclick? Also, to set class attribute, either use `top_ul.setAttribute('class','detclass');` or ` top_ul.className='detclass';`

Comment: @aularon - I think you're right, although IE6 doesn't like `setAttribute('class','detclass')`. It wants "className" instead. I think you would need either *both* `setAttribute()` versions, or just the `top_ul.className` you suggested.

Comment: I am using className no difference if I use setAttribute or .className.  She works onload, but once I click the button, I get the same code, without the styles.

Comment: Cris - Your code works fine for me here. http://jsfiddle.net/7wKVT/ What is in the `showdetails.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Where in your document is this script? Is it possible that the DOM element containing Button1 is not yet loaded when this script is executed? You might try putting this in a script tag after your body, rather than in your head, or wrapping it in a function that is then executed in an onload element.

EDIT: Now that the question has code tags, I can see it is in the script tag. I still recommend wrapping it in a function and calling with onLoad, to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before the script is executed.

Comment: Sorry, the version without the code tag was being displayed when I wrote the above, so I did not see where you had put it. I withdraw my questions.